# Does the standard model predict $\alpha_G^{-1}\approx c_5$ for $m_{proton}$?

Tags: standard-model, quantum-gravity, beyond-the-standard-model, protons, grand-unification

Given $$\alpha_G^{-1} = \frac{m_{planck}^2}{m_{particle\ of\ interest}^2}$$
$$particle\ of\ interest = proton$$
$$c_5 = fifth\ Catalan\ Mersenne\ prime = 2^{(2^{(2^{(2^2-1)}-1)}-1)}-1$$

Does the standard model predict the fact that $\alpha_G^{-1}\approx c_5$ within a 0.5% and better than any of [the hundreds of possible massive particles of interest](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParticleData.html) including the neutron?

If so, why?

Comment: The Standard Model has nothing to do with gravity, $G$, the Planck mass, or prime numbers. Furthermore, as far as I know, it is only a conjecture that $c_5$ is prime.

Comment: This idea is in the work of Bastin and Noyes, e.g. https://inspirehep.net/literature/140998  You might have better luck asking for comment on their theories specifically.

Answer (score 1):

No, it makes no such prediction. All the alpha constants in the standard model are free parameters and thus only enumerated by experiment. If you were to find a theoretical derivation of any value in terms of other physical and mathematical constants, you would have a very quick Nobel Prize lined up for you. Until such a theoretical framework is discovered, any attempt at comparing the values of these constants to any exact mathematical expression is simply coincidence and numerology.